# How can I check if the pixels are empty or not?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a picture. I want to pixel this image with OpenCv and check whether the pixels are empty or not. How can I do it?
[for example this image](https://www.nedir.org/resim-ekle/yazi-resmi/896/1392386990_18_896.jpg)

Comment: What did you try up to now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if by 'empty' pixel you mean white, you can do this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('imp.jpg')

pixel = np.argwhere(img == 255)
```

Comment: Yes, when I said blank, I meant it to be white :) Thank you.